# Spotify Related Artist Outputs Undefined names

Tags: javascript, api, spotify, spotify-app

I'm trying to get a list of related artists but am returning mixed results. Sometimes the name of the related artist will appear and sometimes it will return "undefined".

How do I retrieve the names of all the related artists without getting an "undefined" result?

```
       models.Artist
          .fromURI('spotify:artist:7hJcb9fa4alzcOq3EaNPoG')
          .load(artist_properties)
          .done(function(artist){

            artist.related.snapshot().done(function(r){

              var relatedArtists = r.toArray();
              var relatedArtistsNames = [];
              var i;

              for(i = 0; i < relatedArtists.length; i++){
                var listItem = document.createElement("li");
                listItem.innerHTML = relatedArtists[i].name;
                $('#relatedContainer').append(listItem);
              }
            });
          });
```

This outputs:

[image]

Comment: looks like the `.toArray()` call is causing the problem, having not used this API, can't say for sure. those undefineds could be methods on `r` that get confused when converting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your next question, I'd say you already figured out snapshot.loadAll('name'), but I'll throw it on here for posterity.